Docker Compose for AirFlow (Source: SQL Server and destination: MongoDB) not working
Has anyone ever implemented AirFlow where source = SQL Server and
destination = Mongodb? I am not getting working connection for SQL Server and Mongodb in Airflow documentation.
Does anyone have a Docker file with these two connections setup?
I have tried this:
DockerFile
# Dockerfile
FROM apache/airflow:2.2.0

# Install additional packages
USER root
RUN pip install apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql

# Switch back to airflow user
USER airflow

docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  airflow:
    build:
      context: ./  # Path to the directory containing Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "9001:8080"  # Adjust ports as needed
    environment:
      - AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR=LocalExecutor  # Example Airflow configuration
      - AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__RBAC=true
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags  # Mount DAGs directory
      - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs  # Mount logs directory
      - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins  # Mount plugins directory
    command: webserver  # Command to start Airflow webserver

But this code is not working.

But this code is not working. Why not? What error message(s) do you get?

Can't speak to mongodb, but for Airflow versus SQL Server you need to apt-get install build-essential manpages-dev unixodbc-dev and pip install apache-airflow-providers-odbc apache-airflow-providers-microsoft-mssql in each of the webserver, worker and scheduler containers, assuming you started with something like the example from https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.8.0/docker-compose.yaml

Hi everyone, I have established the connection using this article :
https://girishdeshpande.medium.com/apache-airflow-on-docker-ms-sql-server-etl-dag-a8317da5cbcc
